# Why does code that requires user input not work in the Rust Playground?

Tags: rust

I copy pasted the code from *The Rust Programming Language* under the [heading "Processing a Guess"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html#processing-a-guess) onto the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/). However, there is no prompt shown in the standard output. I have searched for this problem and I think that this may be one of the "limitations" that [the help lists](https://play.rust-lang.org/help).

I have decided that I should use some software that will help me code without the Playground, but I do not have an IDE set up yet, and that is not part of my question anyhow.

What I have tried to do is copy paste the following code onto the Rust playground:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}
```

The result is that it will compile properly without any panic attacks, errors, or warnings, and print to the 'standard output' the following:

```
Guess the number!
Please input your guess.
You guessed:
```

The information in Listing 2-1 in the book tells us that this code should be able to get a guess from the user and the print that guess (as a string).

My expectation is that I would be able to click on the line in the 'standard output' where it says:

```
You guessed:
```

but when I click on the white-space to the right of the colon, and start typing, no new string appears.

Am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: There is nothing connected to standard input in the playground. Download rust and run it on your computer. `I have decided that I should use some software that will help me code without the Playground but I do not have an IDE set up yet, and that is not part of my question anyhow.` You don't need an IDE to get started. Rust itself and a simple texteditor work fine.

Comment: Hi @tkausl , thanks for the input. But how do i download rust and how do I use a text editor?

Comment: `But how do i download rust` Download RustUp from https://www.rust-lang.org/learn/get-started `and how do I use a text editor?` I'm not sure I understand this question; have you never used a text-editor on your machine?

Comment: I downloaded rustup, rustc, and cargo & don't remember deleting them. I don't think I've ever used a text editor before.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Playground does [not currently accept user input via stdin](https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/issues/22). The stdin is effectively closed immediately, thus your program gets no input and moves on to the next line of code, printing the "guess", which is just the empty string.

> that this may be one of the "limitations" that the help lists.

It is not, but probably should be.

Source: I am the creator of the playground.